# De HTML form a Python y de vuelta a HTML

Tags: html, python, flask

Es algo sencillo, estoy usando Flask, y quiero tomar un input de HTML (una contraseña), comparar con Python si esta es correcta, y en el **mismo HTML** colocar si esta es correcta o no (sin que se redirija a una nueva HTML). Algo así sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <form action="/checkingPass" method="post">
    <label for="nombreUser"> Ingrese contraseña: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombreUser"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
    <!-- QUE AQUÍ APAREZCA: Es correcta/No es correcta -->
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.py`:

```py
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def checkinPass():
    # AQUI DEBERÍA TOMAR EL VALOR DEL INPUT INGRESADO Y 
    # COMPARARLO CON UNA CONTRASEÑA DETERMINADA
    # MANDARLO A UN ESPACIO ASIGNADO EN index.html

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True)
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: una pregunta, por pregunta ;).. esto no es un foro.. si tenes otra pregunta, haces otra pregunta....

Comment: ya la formulé slds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero hay que cambiar el `action` del formulario, ya que pasaríamos a procesar la petición en la misma ruta, es decir en la raíz(/)

Esto

```
action="/checkingPass"
```

Por

```
 action="/"
```

Por otra parte, en la plantilla `html`, tenemos que añadir una seria de comprobaciones haciendo uso de [Jinja](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/templating/), es decir

```
{% if passwd_status == True %}
    <div>Es correcta</div>
{% elif passwd_status == False %}
    <div>No es correcta</div>
{% endif %}
```

Con esto estamos diciendo que si la variable `passwd_status` es `True`  significa que el usuario ha introducido bien la contraseña, en caso contrario, le mostraremos el mensaje de error. Dicho esto tu `html` quedara de la siguiente manera.

```
<html>
  <body>
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <label for="nombreUser"> Ingrese contraseña: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombreUser"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
    <!--Check jinja-->
    {% if passwd_status == True %}
        <div>Es correcta</div>
    {% elif passwd_status == False %}
        <div>No es correcta</div>
    {% endif %}

  </body>
</html>
```

Bien, ahora miremos la logia de Flask.

Primero, deberíamos de decirle a la ruta que aceptamos peticiones `GET` y `POST`, para eso hacemos añadimos el parámetro `methods` a nuestro `app.router`

```
@app.route('/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
```

Después tendremos que mirar si el método es `GET` o `POST` y aplicar la  lógica  en cada una de las peticiones.

Dicho esto, tu código en flask quedara así mas o menos.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def checkinPass():
    # Flag para guardar el estado del login
    passwd_status = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Devolvemos passwd_status None.
        return render_template("index.html", passwd_status=passwd_status)
    else:
        # Recogemos el valor que nos manda el usuario
        data = request.form.get('nombreUser')
        if data == '1234':
            # El valor es correcto
            passwd_status = True
        else:
            passwd_status = False
        # Devolvemos la misma plantilla y si el valor es valido o no
        return render_template("index.html", passwd_status=passwd_status)
```

#### Ampliación

Para implementarlo con `fetch`, sería de la siguiente manera.

Flask:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def checkinPass():
    # Flag para guardar el estado del login
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        passwd_status = False
        # Recogemos el valor que nos manda el usuario
        data = request.form.get('nombreUser')
        if data == '1234':
            # El valor es correcto
            passwd_status = True
        # Devolvemos un dict(json) con los resultados
        return {'passwd_status': passwd_status}
```

HTML/JS

```
<html>
  <body>
  <form action="/" method="post" id="formP" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="nombreUser"> Ingrese contraseña: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombreUser"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
  <h2 id="message"></h2>
 <script>

    document.querySelector("#formP").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();    //paramos la ejecucion del formulario
        form = new FormData(this)
        fetch(this.action, {
          method: 'post',
          body: form
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(resp => {
          const el = document.querySelector("#message")
          if(resp.passwd_status === true) {
            el.innerHTML = 'Contraseña correcta'
          } else {
            el.innerHTML = 'Contraseña incorrecta'
          }
        })
    });

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que el OP no quiere que se vuelva a renderizar un template

Comment: @MitaCloud eres un genio, me funciona a la perfección. Gracias por tomarte un tiempo para detallarme todo y explicar el paso a paso. Te aplaudo

Comment: Cuando la quiero utilizar por segunda vez, ¿hay una manera simple para que al actualizar (F5), el mensaje "Es correcta" / "No es correcta" que había quedado del primer intento, desaparezca?

Comment: Ahí ya deberías de hacer uso de los redirects hacia otra página(ruta) o implementar la solución que comenta @Christian, igualmente te dejo una ampliación de como seria

Comment: Buenisimo! Lo ultimo con lo que te voy a molestar @MitaCloud, agregué 2 input en el html para sumarlos, y no lo estoy logrando. Agrego mas abajo el detalle:

Comment: (Lo agregué como una Ampliación)

Comment: @federico eso es otra pregunta.

Comment: @MitaCloud tuve que crear un nuevo hilo para poder sumar los numeros:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/507362/de-html-input-numero-y-pass-python-muestra-resultado-en-html

Answer (score 3):

No necesitas de python, sino de JavaScript. Debes hacer una petición AJAX hacia una ruta de flask y según el resultado JavaScript modificará el HTML.

La forma más fácil y actual de hacer las peticiones es usando la api `fetch` propia de JavaScript. Esta devuelve una promesa y por ende se debe usar `asyn/await`, `callbacks` o  resolviendo con `.then()`

```js
async function verify(){
  let campo_password = document.getElementById("campo_password");
  let data = {password: campo_password}
  const request= await fetch('/', {
    method:"POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  const response = await request.json();
  let msg = document.getElementById("result");
  if(response.result){
    msg.innerHtml="Es correcto"
  }else{
    msg.innerHtml = "Es incorrecto"
  }
}
```

Y en tu ruta (la cual cambiaría de nombre, ya que el `/` indica la ruta principal), tendrías que hacer el proceso de validación y retornar `True` o `False`

```py
from flask import request

@app.route('/checkpass')
def checkinPass():
    password = request.json['password']
    # haces cualquier verificacion
    if password == "algo":
        return {"result": True}
    return {"result": False}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo el detalle, voy a implementarlo también. Saludos!