# De HTML input numero y pass - Python - Muestra resultado en HTML

Tags: html, python, json, flask, fetch

Este es el código que agregué para sumar dos números tal como habíamos visto en el otro hilo. Tiene que arrojar el resultado solo si la contraseña ingresada es correcta (transcribo abajo los códigos completos, con los cuales no se está arrojando 'passwd_status' ni 'suma':

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

index.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def checkinPass():
    n1 = request.form.get('n1') 
    n2 = request.form.get('n2') 
   
    # Flag para guardar el estado del login
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        passwd_status = False
        # Recogemos el valor que nos manda el usuario
        data = request.form.get('nombreUser')
        if data == '1234':
            # El valor es correcto
            passwd_status = True
            suma = int(n1) + int(n2) # ACÁ HAY UN PROBLEMA
        # Devolvemos un dict(json) con los resultados
        return {'passwd_status': passwd_status, 'suma': suma} # ACÁ PUEDE HABER OTRO PROBLEMA

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/" method="post" id="formP" autocomplete="off">
      <label for="n1"> Ingresa el n1 </label>
      <input type="text" name="n1"><br/>
      <label for="n2"> Ingresa el n2 </label>
      <input type="text" name="n2"><br/>
      <label for="nombreUser"> Ingrese contraseña: </label>
      <input type="text" name="nombreUser"><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
  <h2 id="message"></h2>
 <script>

    document.querySelector("#formP").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();    // paramos la ejecucion del formulario
        form = new FormData(this)
        fetch(this.action, {
          method: 'post',
          body: form
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(resp => {
          const el = document.querySelector("#message")
          if(resp.passwd_status == true) {
            el.innerHTML = 'Contraseña correcta. La suma es: ' + suma // ACÁ PUEDE HABER UN PROBLEMA
          } else {
            el.innerHTML = 'Contraseña incorrecta'
          }
        })
    });

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Al hacer una pregunta se la haces a toda la comunidad, no a un solo usuario. Tu pregunta carece de detalles para que pueda ser respondida, pues solo aquel que haya leido toda tu pregunta anterior sabrá que estas haciendo. Por favor lee [ask] para que sepas como elaborar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Te hubiera votado negativo, pero prefiero que sepas cual es el error que cometes antes de emitir uno.

Comment: está ok así? @Christian gracias por la sugerencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta respuestas en la continuación de las [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/507235/de-html-form-a-python-y-de-vuelta-a-html/507249?noredirect=1#comment900865_507249)

Tienes que recoger los valores en el método post(else) ya que es ahí donde el JS enviara los datos, es decir el código seria el siguiente

```
@app.route('/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def checkinPass():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        # Aqui se va a ejecutar el metodo post
        # Ya que solo aceptamos post y get

        # Dict donde vamos a guardar la informacion
        payload = {
            'passwd_status': False,
            'suma': 0 # Puedes dejar este valor por defecto o quitarlo.
        }

        # Recogemos el valor que nos manda el usuario
        data = request.form.get('nombreUser')

        try:
            # Recogemos los numeros que envia el usuario
            # Y ademas los intentamos convertir en enteros 
            # para despues poder sumarlos
            n1 = int(request.form.get('n1', 0))
            n2 = int(request.form.get('n2', 0))
        except ValueError as e:
            # Si la conversion a enternos no se ha podido hacer
            # Enviamos de vuelta una tupla con un dict vacio y el codigo de la peticion 400(bad request)
            return {}, 400

        if data == '1234':
            # El valor es correcto
            payload['passwd_status'] = True
            # Añadimos el resultado de la suma a nuestro payload

            payload['suma'] = n1 + n2
        # Devolvemos el payload con la info en caso de que todo haya ido bien.
        return payload
```

Bien, ahora en nuestro javascript, debemos de buscar esas propiedades(passwd_status y suma) en la variable `resp` en este caso, es decir de esta manera.

```
document.querySelector("#formP").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    // paramos la ejecucion del formulario
    let form = new FormData(this)
    fetch(this.action, {
      method: this.method,
      body: form
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(resp => {
      const el = document.querySelector("#message")
      if(resp.passwd_status == true) {
        el.innerHTML = 'Contraseña correcta. La suma es: ' + resp.suma
      } else {
        el.innerHTML = 'Contraseña incorrecta'
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: Excelente @MitaCloud. Es justo lo que buscaba. Gracias por toda la explicación paso a paso. Un lujo.